# Getting expected a function error in Lodash's flow

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to use lodash's `flow` function in my project and started learning from an example below it looks ok but getting `Expected a function` error.

**Source Code:**

```
const foundUser = {
    charData: []
};
const rows = [{ok: 1, blah: 'nope'}];
const myFunction = d => ({ ...d, myProp: 4 });

_.flow([
 _.assign(rows[0]),
 myFunction,
 _.omit('blah'),
])(foundUser);
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_.flow` expects all values in the array to be functions. Your first and third elements are already applied functions and produced a value.

You need to make them functions and supply the proper argument at the right position:

```
_.flow([
 x => _.assign(rows[0], x),
 myFunction,
 x => _.omit(x, 'blah'),
])(foundUser);
```

### Edit: use _.curry instead of inline function

```
_.flow([
 _.curry(_.assign, 2)(rows[0]),
 myFunction,
 _.curryRight(_.omit, 2)('blah'),
])(foundUser);
```

I leave it up to you to decide which you like more.

Comment: Thanks, @Saskia but this working fine function square(n) {
  return n * n;
}
_.flow([_.add, square])(1, 2);

instead of 

function square(n) {
  return n * n;
}
_.flow([(x, y) =>_.add(x, y), square])(1, 2);

Comment: those two examples are more or less the same. see how the `square` in the first one doesn't have parenthesis. So it's not applying the function, it's merely passing the function as a value.
I had to be explicit about the inline function because of how `assign` and `omit` are defined.